# My image has enlarged poorly

Tags: enlarging

i have a picture, that was taken on my daughters camera, that I sent to Walmart online to get enlarged.
It enlarged very poorly.
I have zero photography knowledge,is there a business that can take my photo and make the resolution on it better so that i can get it nicely enlarged?
Thanks,

Kim

Comment: I would start with a local photography shop instead of Wal-Mart.

Comment: You need to check the original image in the camera is high enough resolution to enlarge. A local photography shop would be able to help, as dpollitt suggested. Of course, what is acceptable image quality to you is a personal judgement.

Comment: this is very hard to answer without seeing the file you sent to walmart and the enlargement (what means "poorly" to you?) chances are, the answer is "no, no business can make the resolution better but maybe you did something wrong when ordering the print."

Comment: We need more information to adequately answer your question. What kind of camera took the photo? If it was a film camera, what type of film was used (e.g. Fuji Fujicolor Superia X-TRA400) and how was it scanned to send it online? If it was digital, what is the resolution of the image file (e.g. 6000x4000 pixels, 4000x3000 pixels, etc.)? How was the image transferred online?

Answer (score 2):

You can't improve resolution beyond what was captured when the photo was taken.  Any processing you can do would just be to alter the look a little, which may improve apparent sharpness or reduce apparent noise but won't actually enhance the detail in the way that you could if you had more resolution from the start.

Assuming that it was a decent modern camera, it should have more than enough resolution in it to begin with even for fairly large enlargements (eg 20 inches long) without it looking terrible.

I would suspect that the camera is not set to record at its highest resolution (check in its settings), or the tool you used to upload to Wal-mart reduced the resolution of the phone as you uploaded it.

Take the original photo file in to a photo store or camera shop and have them print it from that.

Answer (score 0):

Check on line or ask the people at a local camera shop. You are seeking an independent one-hour photo lab near you. Take them your camera and or the storage media, if film, take them the negative. They will advise you as to them maximum size print they can make with satisfactory acuity.